# what does "jump in" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence what does the `jump` in mean? (Does it mean hurry or sth like that?)

"The best way to appreciate a software development framework is to jump right in and use it "

---

Obviously I know the meaning of either `jump` and `in` but I have no idea about the former sentence.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/jump-in

Comment: @snailplane- thanks, it's useful. specially the complementary terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *jump in* is used as a phrasal verb here. It means...

> [jump in (ph.v.)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/jump+in#jump_1__198) - to start to do something very quickly without spending a long time thinking first

This means, if you want to know how great a software development framework works and performs, have no second thought, start using it right now.

Comment: Nice, as always.

Comment: Is `right` for more emphasis in _jump right in_?

Comment: @mok Yup. He'd have used *right in* as well.

Answer (score 4):

"jump in" in the context of that sentence means to learn by doing. In this case, it sounds like the advice is to pick a software development framework and try to use it without spending a lot of time reading about how to use it, the theory behind it, and so on.

The addition of "right" ("jump right in") also suggests doing so immediately, similar to language immersion or other situations where common advice is to learn by doing the activity in question.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that some piece software were a car, and driving that car meant using the software. So you just jump in and drive (use) it. To jump in a car means, of course, to get into it.